# How disable auto-retrieval of OTP from SMS in firebase phone verification android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need help with firebase phone verification process. Everything works good but I notice one functionality of firebase, when the OTP code arrives it automatically detect and verify the code. This functionality is called "Auto-retrieval". But I not want this behavior, I want the user to manually put the code and then verify. How I disable this auto retrieve behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Custom Auth** Sorry for not having any example but [Firebase CustomAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) may clear up your questions. what I have thought about this question is that

1- With custom auth, you need a **CustomToken** to log in.

2- So to do that, create and send a custom token to the user and then complete the custom auth by passing **CustomAuth** like.

```
mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(mCustomToken)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // do something on auth success
            } else {
                // do something on auth failed
              
            }
    }
```

**Question**
Why do you want to make an application's process manual when its already automated and only made for the ease of user?

Comment: the client requirement is manual but now i explain the client about this automated process. Thank you brother once again!